# Finding out the public key of an ssh server

Tags: unix, ssh, public-key

I have access to a student server and was interested in being able to visualize the public key of the ssh server. What unix command can help me see the ssh key, since this is different than my own generating of keys like on AWS etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is that simple as :

```
# cat /root/.ssh/id*.pub
```

or for a specific user :

```
# cat ~user/.ssh/id*.pub
```